# JAX @jit for nested class method

Tags: nested, jit, jax

I am trying to use `@jit` with nested function, having a problem.
I have a class `One` that take in another class `Plant` with a method `func`.
I would like to call this method jitted `func` from `One`.
I think that I followed the FAQ of JAX, "How to use jit with methods?" section.
https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq.html#how-to-use-jit-with-methods
However, I encountered an error saying that
`TypeError: One.__init__() got multiple values for argument 'plant'`.
Would anyone tell me how to solve this?

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import grad, jit, vmap
from jax import random
import numpy as np
from functools import partial
from jax import tree_util

class One:
    def __init__(self, plant,x):
        self.plant = plant
        self.x = x
    
    @jit
    def call_plant_func(self,y):
        out = self.plant.func(y) + self.x
        return out
    
    def _tree_flatten(self):
        children = (self.x,)  # arrays / dynamic values
        aux_data = {'plant':self.plant}  # static values
        return (children, aux_data)

    @classmethod
    def _tree_unflatten(cls, aux_data, children):
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace();
        return cls(*children, **aux_data)
        
tree_util.register_pytree_node(One,
                               One._tree_flatten,
                               One._tree_unflatten)    
    
class Plant:
    def __init__(self, z,kk):
        self.z =z
    
    @jit
    def func(self,y):
        y = y + self.z
        return y
    
    def _tree_flatten(self):
        children = (self.z,)  # arrays / dynamic values
        aux_data = None # static values
        return (children, aux_data)

    @classmethod
    def _tree_unflatten(cls, children):
        return cls(*children)
   
tree_util.register_pytree_node(Plant,
                               Plant._tree_flatten,
                               Plant._tree_unflatten)

plant = Plant(5,2)
one = One(plant,2)
print(one.call_plant_func(10))
```

The last line gives me an error described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues in the `tree_flatten` and `tree_unflatten` code in both classes.

- `One._tree_flatten` treats `plant` as static data, but it is not: it is a pytree that has non-static elements.
- `One._tree_unflatten` instantiates `One` with arguments in the wrong order, leading to the error you're seeing
- `Plant.__init__` does nothing with the `kk` argument.
- `Plant._tree_unflatten` is missing the `aux_data` argument, and fails to pass the `kk` argument to `Plant.__init__`

With these issues fixed, your code executes without error:

```py
class One:
    def __init__(self, plant,x):
        self.plant = plant
        self.x = x
    
    @jit
    def call_plant_func(self,y):
        out = self.plant.func(y) + self.x
        return out
    
    def _tree_flatten(self):
        children = (self.plant, self.x)
        aux_data = None
        return (children, aux_data)

    @classmethod
    def _tree_unflatten(cls, aux_data, children):
        return cls(*children)
        
tree_util.register_pytree_node(One,
                               One._tree_flatten,
                               One._tree_unflatten)    
    
class Plant:
    def __init__(self, z, kk):
        self.kk = kk
        self.z =z
    
    @jit
    def func(self, y):
        y = y + self.z
        return y
    
    def _tree_flatten(self):
        children = (self.z, self.kk)
        aux_data = None
        return (children, aux_data)

    @classmethod
    def _tree_unflatten(cls, aux_data, children):
        return cls(*children)
   
tree_util.register_pytree_node(Plant,
                               Plant._tree_flatten,
                               Plant._tree_unflatten)

plant = Plant(5,2)
one = One(plant,2)
print(one.call_plant_func(10))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, and I am sorry for posting a messy code.